# How to prevent code from inside a cell from running while CollectionView is being Reloaded

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a full size cell that plays video so there is only 1 cell on the screen at a time. When I scroll up and down the videos stop and play like they're supposed to, I have no issues whatsoever.

The problem occurs when `reloadData` is called.

I paginate when the user gets to the 2nd to last item inside the datasource. If the user is at that 2nd to last item and is playing a video, when the pagination pulls the data and `reloadData` is called, the current video inside the cell gets disrupted because cellForItem keeps running for each new item added the datasource.

I tried adding a Bool property to the data model and checked to see if it's true, if so return but that didn't work

How can I prevent the code from inside the currently visible scell from executing once `reloadData` is called?:

```
class Video {
    var url: URL?
    var videoId: String?
    var postDate: Double?
    var isUserWatchingVideo = false
}

var dataSource = [Video]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

     cell.currentItem = indexPath.item
     cell.video = dataSource[indexPath.item]
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didEndDisplaying cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    // stop video from playing inside cell
    // reset the isUserWatchingVideo property to false
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    
    // when the user gets to the 2nd to last item inside the dataSource start to paginate
    handlePagination()
}

func handlePagination() {

    // new items are found and called for each new item added
    dataSource.append(video)
    dataSource.sort(by: { $0.postDate ?? 0 > $1.postDate ?? 0 })
    collectionView.reloadData // problem occurs once this runs because cellForItem && didEndDisplayingCell runs for each new item that was added
}
```

inside cell:

```
MyCell {

    var currentItem: Int?

    var video: Video? {
        didSet {
            guard let video = video else { return }

            if video.isUserWatchingVideo { return }

            if !video.isUserWatchingVideo {
                video.isUserWatchingVideo = true
            } 
            // get url > asset > playerItem > player
            cell.player.play()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to change your approach while loading new items via pagination. Instead of reloading the entire `UICollectionView` while new data is loaded, you've to use insert items to append new cells.

```
func handlePagination() {
    dataSource.append(video)
    collectionView.insertItems(at: <#T##[IndexPath]#>)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! 2 questions 1. don't I have to still call reloadData so that the collectionView knows the new dataSource has new items in it (I never used **insertItems** before)? 2. How do I know which item to add to the indexPath? There is only 1 section. For eg. IndexPath(item: ???, section: 0)

Comment: 1. You don't have to call reloadData again. 2. Create an indexPath if only 1 section means section: 0 and provide the item index according to the number of items.

Comment: Like this **1.** dataSource.append(video) **2.**  let lastIndex = dataSource.count **3.** let indexPath = IndexPath(item: lastIndex , section: 0), **4.** collectionView.insertItems(at: indexPath)

Comment: Either take the last index before appending or the last index - 1 if it's after appending. You'll get an index out of range error. Just try it out on your code. It's simple enough.